# Should I store $(document).height() and/or $(window).height() as variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, variables

Is it a good idea to store these values as variables (outside of .scroll() ) in the following example?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ( $(document).height() <= ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
    // position stuff
  } else {
    // other position stuff
  }
});
```

The only downside to this I see is that the heights *should* be checked again in case of a window resize. Or do I only need to store the **objects** themselves?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be careful with the scroll event http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the very least, it's **definitely** a good idea to store references to `$(document)` and `$(window)` outside of the `scroll` callback, since the scroll event might be fired repeatedly and rapidly.

```
var $win = $(window),
    $doc = $(document);

$win.scroll(function(){
  if ( $doc.height() <= ( $win.height() + $win.scrollTop() ) ) {
    // position stuff
  } else {
    // other position stuff
  }
});
```

It shouldn't hurt to do as you ask, and store the document and window heights outside of the callback as well — provided that you update them as needed. A nice way to handle all of this is to use the excellent [jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), which gives you a simple interface for making sure a function doesn't run too frequently.

Answer (score 1):

i do the same thing but i add on something else:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ( $(document).height() <= ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
    // position stuff
  } else {
    // other position stuff
  }
}).resize(function(){$(this).scroll()});//will call the scroll method on resize
```

or what you can do is this:

```
function pageSizer(){
      if ( $(document).height() <= ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
        // position stuff
      } else {
        // other position stuff
      }
}

$(window).scroll(pageSizer).resize(pageSizer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the chaining tip, @Neal

Answer (score 0):

Store `$(document)` and `$(window)`, but re-check the height() and scrollTop() as this can change based on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Every-time you wrap an Element with jQuery you are creating a jQuery object. If you plan to use that same jQuery object many times, then caching it is a wise thing to do. This is done by storing it in a variable and just call the variable everytime you want to use it. This will not longer create a jQuery object, but rather use the cached version.

Ex:

```
var wh = $(window).height();
```